# apt: Prevent ms edge from upgrading frequently

Tags: apt, upgrade

I've installed microsoft edge for office 365 and i'm using it but it upgrades very frequently like each 2 or 3 day. current upgrade is `microsoft-edge-stable/stable 116.0.1938.69-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 116.0.1938.62-1]` I know i can prevent it from updating using `apt-mark hold` but i want major upgrades like 116 to 117, is there some option in apt making it so ?

Comment: Apt-marking has no such logic. You could script it yourself, but there are risks: Running an unpatched browser risks compromise.